# showing result of one column if another column value is true

Tags: excel, vlookup

I want to get result if number is 11, that print me fb links(in this case result is only 1 fb link)...I tried with vlookup..But couldn't find result...

I have twho columns, one is numbers, and another is fb links.

Comment: I can't  view your image, can you try to submit it again ?

Answer (score 0):

Vlookup actually *should* work. Try the following:

> =VLOOKUP(lookup_value,range,column_index_number)

Typically for a table in the first 2 columns, that would be:

> =VLOOKUP(11,A2:B12,2)

Comment: thank, but i solved earlier...Its a bit more complicated function, without vlook up :) but thanks! :)